# C# service won't write to XML

Tags: c#, service

I've just written a test service in C# 2010.  In the OnStart method i'm opening an XML document in the root of C: drive, parsing it and writing out to another XML document also in the root of C: drive.

When I install the service and start it, im told it stopped again automatically. The output XML file is created but is empty.  I'm running the service as Local System account.

Can anyone tell me why no content is being written?

Thanks,

EDIT (to include code for OnStart)...

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    String win32ClassName = "";
    String nodeSubkeyName = "";
    List<String> propertyList = new List<String>();
    List<String> propertyListQuery = new List<String>();

    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\hwin.xml");
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\hwout.xml", null);
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteComment("Asset hardware Inventory for " + System.Environment.MachineName);
    writer.WriteStartElement("hardware");
```

The above code doesn't even write the starting element for the output XML file, but it does create the empty file so suspect it has rights to do that.  Perhaps reading the input file IS the issue?  I've little to no idea how the Local Service account works!

Comment: so it actually writes the file to disk? but it's empty.. very strange!

Comment: I think it is a problem of right on the created file. Post a little part of your code maybe we can help you

Comment: Guess you have closed the WriteStartElement with WriteEndElement and also closed the writer once you have finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably an unhandled exception....

Use Try/Catch, write exception to system.diagnostics.trace.writeline and use DebugView(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to read the output.

Comment: Turned out to be an unhandled exception in what I was reading for the XML.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect that it's not flushing the stream it's writing to. Stream output (including file output) is normally buffered because it gives better performance to batch up a bunch of bytes to write to the file rather than do them one by one. (The benefit increases the larger buffer you use until either 4 or 8k, at which point the cost of the memory used outweighs the gain. 4 and 8 both tend to be better than something in between because they also hit memory page sizes well, in any case the default buffers for most framework-supplied streams is 4k).

Anyway, if that is the problem, then you need to flush the stream. This is always done when you close the writer, and closing the writer is always done when you `Dispose()` it. You should always dispose anything that implements `IDisposable` as soon as possible anyway as a matter of good practice (always assume something bad at least could happen if you don't, even in those cases where you know a given `Dispose()` is currently implemented as a no-op). Most of the time, this is most easily done with a using block:

```
using(XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\hwout.xml", null))
{
  //code that uses writer here
}
```

Even if my suspicion is wrong, it's well worth getting into the habit of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error log in event viewer, its most likely you don't have permission to read the file from c:\

You can make the service run under an account which has permission to read\write to c:\

You should use a try and catch around your xml write code block, and then log the error to debug this further.

Comment: I thought that Local Service account would have permissions to C: (or any part of the disk)?  Is this not the case?

Comment: Most likely no, i don't remember - easiest is to just open the service panel and change the user the server is running under and change it your account which can read and write the file on c:\. if making this change works then you know for sure its the permission issue. long term fix you should have a try and catch and log exceptions

Comment: I usually find the best way to write a services is to put all your logic into a class library...then during development i use the class library with a console application...and also use the same code for the wndows service too. Example MyClassLibrary.RunInstance()...that's all the code that i need to put in the console application and the windows service. Rest of the code goes is the class library. Much easier to debug this was and much faster, instead of constantly compiling, installinh and uninstalling the service.

Comment: Tried giving it my own details and it does the same thing. Off on a C# course next week, so will look into handling exceptions after that I guess.  I was just messing about anyway, to see how much I could figure out by myself!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without code snippet,but if service doesn't start definitely OnStart throw exception, put Thread.Sleep in OnStart method, attach to process with visual studio and [debug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing your code as a console application rather than a service?

Often run-time issues with services are due to privileges. For the writing part, this is not the case here, because your code got to create the output XML file. Therefore, your service has write rights to the right directory.

But it may be that it does not have read rights on the input file, or there just may be an exception happening during execution.

My advice to you:

- test your code as a Console app rather than a service, and test it from within Visual Studio
- try/catch and log any exceptions
- check the Event Viewer to see if windows has logged any details about the problem with your service

Comment: Yes, the code runs fine as console application.  I'll post code in my original post.